# Finding prime numbers between any range and how to pick out non repeat numbers in python

Tags: python-2.7

i didn't find out how to pick out non repeat numbers in my list(prime numbers), here is my code:

```
lower = int(input("Enter Lower: "))
upper = int(input("Enter Upper: "))

for num in range(lower,upper + 1):
   # prime numbers are greater than 1
   if num > 1:
       for i in range(2,num):
           if (num % i) == 0:
               break
       else:
           print(num)
```

For example i found prime numbers between 100 and 130, which is 
101
103
107
109
113
127

ok but how can i print just "103,107,109,127" ? 
**1**0**1**, **11**3 is repeating numbers. 
set(num) function didn't work.
Thank you so much.

Comment: please elaborate on which numbers exactly you dont want to print out and why

Comment: why is 101 and 113 repeating?

Comment: Oh, i am sorry. Digits is repeating. i want to choose different digits. ex. 107 not repeating digits.

Comment: how many digits have to repeat to be considered a dupe?

Comment: if the prime numbers same digits, i don't want to choose them.

Between 10 and 70 prime numbers: 
11 ----- same digit 
13 ---- different digit OK
17 OK
19 OK
23 OK
29 OK
31 OK
37 OK
41 OK
43 OK
47 OK
53 OK
59 OK
61 OK
67 OK

i mean i don't want to in my list "11" because same digit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it by reducing the number by one digit each time, any 10 digit or greater number is going to contain dupes:

```
def is_unique(n):
    if n > 9999999999:
        return False
    st = set()
    while n:
        n, rem = divmod(n, 10)
        if rem in st:
            return False
        st.add(rem)
    return True
```

Just check if before you print it:

```
lower = int(input("Enter Lower: "))
upper = int(input("Enter Upper: "))


for num in range(lower, upper + 1):
    # prime numbers are greater than 1
    if num > 1:
        for i in range(2, num):
            if (num % i) == 0:
                break
        else:
            if is_unique(num):
                print(num)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change your printing routine to the following

```
# Convert to a string
str_num = str(num)
# Check whether the length of the string is equal to the number
# of unique digits using a set
repeating = len(set(str_num)) != len(str_num)
# Print if there are no repeating digits
if not repeating:
    print num
```

Comment: thank you so much, just i will add your code end of the my code? but it didn't work. i will try.

Comment: i got it, thank you. i didn't get error messages, but i saw same prime numbers. (same digits)

Answer (score 0):

use this filter function to filter only numbers which contain no digit more than once:

```
def filter(num):
    num_str = str(num)
    return len(set(num_str)) == len(num_str)
```

like this:

```
if filter(...):
    print(...)
```